# Error in connecting with Php app in Android

Tags: php, android, http-post

Here is my code to send the data from android app to php app which is running in my localhost. It is showing "Connection to http:// localhost refused" . Please help me

```
public void postData() throws JSONException
{

    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/xampp/FeelSafeSecurity/connectiondemo.php");

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    try {
        // prepare JSON data:
        json.put("name", "santhosh");
        json.put("age", "24");

        JSONArray postjson=new JSONArray();
        postjson.put(json);

        // Post the data:
        httppost.setHeader("json", json.toString());
        httppost.getParams().setParameter("jsonpost",postjson);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        System.out.print(json);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        // for JSON:
        if(response != null)
        {
            InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line = null;
            try {
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            text = sb.toString();
        }

        tv.setText(text);

    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage()); 
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace(); 
    }
}
```

And here is my php code to receive the data. I'am new to PHP.

```
<?php
$json = $_SERVER['HTTP_JSON'];
echo "JSON: \n";
echo "--------------\n";
var_dump($json);
echo "\n\n";

$data = json_decode($json);
echo "Array: \n";
echo "--------------\n"; 
var_dump($data); 
echo "\n\n";

echo "Result: \n";
echo "--------------\n";
echo "\n\nName     : ".$data->name."\n\n Age : ".$data->age;
?>
```

Comment: Your Android app is not running on the server the site runs on, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use localhost use your IP address. Localhost is only for the LOCAL server

Comment: Thanks. It's working. Now i'am able to see the data (name & age ) on emulator. But How can i get the same data on php side?

Comment: i'am not getting name and age on php side

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` means the local machine on which the app executes. In your case either amdroid device or the emulator virtual machine. Neither of which is running your php server.

So, if you run this on device you must use the IP of the machine where php code is running.

If you are trying this on emulator and you host machine runs the php code then you might try `10.0.2.2` as described in [emulator network addressing](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).